# Symbols ($(bindir), $(sysconfdir),...) unknown in (sub) Makefiles

Tags: makefile, autotools

I'm working with autotools for the first time, for a tool that's written in perl ([SQLTeX](https://github.com/oveas/sqltex)), so only installation is required, no compilation.

The toplevel contains a simple `Makefile.am`:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
SUBDIRS = src man doc

EXTRA_DIST = README.md

.PHONY: all-am
all-am:
    @echo "Done!"
```

If I create `Makefile.am` files in the sub-directories too, nothing seems to happen there so I just stick to `Makefile`. A snippet from [`src/Makefile`](https://github.com/oveas/sqltex/blob/master/src/Makefile) (EDIT: this file is now renamed to [`Makefile.am`](https://github.com/oveas/sqltex/blob/master/src/Makefile.am)):

```
SQLTeX: SQLTeX.pl
    cat $^ | sed -e 's#{PERLDIR}#$(PL)#;s#{SYSCONFDIR}#$(sysconfdir)#' > $@
    @chmod +x $@
```

The symbol `PL` is set as expect (defined in the same makefile), but `sysconfdir` is empty, although it is defined in the top-level `Makefile` generated by `./configure`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the mechanics of automake, but it sounds like you likely need to export your variables.  See [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html) for details

Comment: Although simply adding 'export' to Makefile.am did the trick, I'm going for the answer John Bollinger provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Although the Autotools support, with some caveats, recursing into directories where you provide pre-built makefiles, you cannot expect those pre-built makefiles to be able to rely on autotools-provided variables such as the standard directory variables `bindir` and `sysconfdir`.  Thus, although it is *allowed* to rely on hand-written makefiles in subdirectories, this is probably a false trail for you.

I recommend going back to this:

> If I create `Makefile.am` files in the sub-directories too, nothing seems to happen there

and working out what's wrong.  The Autotools definitely support generating recursive build systems, and one `Makefile.am` per directory is part of the usual approach to that.  If it didn't work for you then my first guess would be that you forgot to list the extra makefiles in your `AC_CONFIG_FILES` list.

As an alternative, just because you have multiple directories does not mean that you need to use recursive `make`.  It is quite possible to build such a project with the support of a single makefile, and the Autotools can help with such a makefile.

Comment: The subdir makefiles were indeed not listed in AC_CONFIG_FILES, so this put me on the right track